# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field java Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

Hi im relative new to java and im getting this error, honestly i dont know exactly where im wrong but at least i think that the annotations @service and @repository are well implemented.

here is the java code:

business layer

```
public interface ISrvIntConsumerCovers {

DtoIntMessageResponse updateConsumerCover(DtoIntConsumerCover dtoIntConsumerCover);

public DtoIntConsumerCover listTypifications(DtoIntConsumerCover dtoIntConsumerCover);

public DtoIntConsumerCover getConsumerCover(String id);

public DtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversOut listPendingStageSanctionCovers(
        DtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversIn dtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversIn);

public DtoIntListConsumerCoversOut listConsumerCovers(DtoIntListConsumerCoversIn consumerCoversIn);    
}
```

business layer implementation

```
@Service
public class SrvIntConsumerCovers implements ISrvIntConsumerCovers {

@Autowired
private ConsumerCoversDAO consumerCreditDAOImpl;

@Override
public DtoIntMessageResponse updateConsumerCover(
        DtoIntConsumerCover dtoIntConsumerCover) {

    return consumerCreditDAOImpl.updateConsumerCover(dtoIntConsumerCover);
}

@Override
public DtoIntConsumerCover listTypifications(
        DtoIntConsumerCover dtoIntConsumerCover) {

    return consumerCreditDAOImpl.listTypification(dtoIntConsumerCover);
}

@Override
public DtoIntConsumerCover getConsumerCover(String id) {

    return consumerCreditDAOImpl.getConsumerCover(id);
}

@Override
public DtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversOut listPendingStageSanctionCovers(
        DtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversIn dtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversIn) {

    return consumerCreditDAOImpl.listPendingStageSanctionCovers(dtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversIn);
}

@Override
public DtoIntListConsumerCoversOut listConsumerCovers(
        DtoIntListConsumerCoversIn ConsumerCoversIn) {

    return consumerCreditDAOImpl.listConsumerCovers(ConsumerCoversIn);
}

}
```

Dao layer

```
public interface ConsumerCoversDAO {

DtoIntMessageResponse updateConsumerCover(DtoIntConsumerCover peticion);

DtoIntConsumerCover listTypification(
        DtoIntConsumerCover dtoConsumerCover);

DtoIntConsumerCover getConsumerCover(String dtoConsumerCover);

public DtoIntListConsumerCoversOut listConsumerCovers(
        DtoIntListConsumerCoversIn consumerCoversIn);

DtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversOut listPendingStageSanctionCovers(
        DtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversIn dtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversIn);
}
```

Dao layer implementation

```
@Repository
public class ConsumerCoversDAOImpl implements ConsumerCoversDAO {

@Autowired
private BackendMapper<Request_1, DtoIntConsumerCover, Response_1, DtoIntMessageResponse> mfadt310Mapper;

@Autowired
private BackendSummoner<Request_1, Response_1> transaccionMfadt310;

@Autowired
private BackendMapper<Request314_1, DtoIntConsumerCover, Response314_1, DtoIntConsumerCover> mfadt314Mapper;

@Autowired
private BackendSummoner<Request314_1, Response314_1> transaccionMfadt314;

@Autowired
private BackendMapper<Request311_1, String, Response311_1, DtoIntConsumerCover> mfadt311Mapper;

@Autowired
private BackendSummoner<Request311_1, Response311_1> transaccionMfadt311;

@Autowired
private BackendMapper<Request312_1, DtoIntListConsumerCoversIn, Response312_1, DtoIntListConsumerCoversOut> mfadt312Mapper;

@Autowired
private BackendSummoner<Request312_1, Response312_1> transaccionMfadt312_1;

@Autowired
BackendMapper<Request313_1, DtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversIn, Response313_1, DtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversOut> mfadt313Mapper;

@Autowired
private BackendSummoner<Request313_1, Response313_1> transaccionMfadt313;

@Override
public DtoIntMessageResponse updateConsumerCover(DtoIntConsumerCover peticion) {

    return mfadt310Mapper.mapToOuter(transaccionMfadt310.invocar(mfadt310Mapper.mapToInner(peticion)));
}

@Override
public DtoIntConsumerCover listTypification(
        DtoIntConsumerCover dtoIntConsumerCover) {
    try {

        return mfadt314Mapper.mapToOuter(
                transaccionMfadt314.invocar(mfadt314Mapper.mapToInner(dtoIntConsumerCover)));
    } catch (ExcepcionRespuestaHost e) {
        if (e.getCodigoError().equals("00903025")) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return mfadt314Mapper.mapToOuter(
                    transaccionMfadt314.invocar(mfadt314Mapper.mapToInner(dtoIntConsumerCover)));
        }

    }

}

@Override
public DtoIntConsumerCover getConsumerCover(String dtoConsumerCover) {
    return mfadt311Mapper
            .mapToOuter(transaccionMfadt311.invocar(mfadt311Mapper.mapToInner(dtoConsumerCover)));
}

@Override
public DtoIntListConsumerCoversOut listConsumerCovers(
        DtoIntListConsumerCoversIn consumerCoversIn) {
    return mfadt312Mapper
            .mapToOuter(transaccionMfadt312_1.invocar(mfadt312Mapper.mapToInner(consumerCoversIn)));
}

@Override
public DtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversOut listPendingStageSanctionCovers(
        DtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversIn dtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversIn) {
    return mfadt313Mapper.mapToOuter(
            transaccionMfadt313.invocar(mfadt313Mapper.mapToInner(dtoIntListPendingStageSanctionCoversIn)));
}

}
```

BackendMapper class

```
public interface BackendMapper<P, I, R, O> {


P mapToInner(I input);


O mapToOuter(R response);
}
```

Error trace:

```
Service is CORRUPTED and will not accept any request: BusinessServiceDeployment       [deploymentType=BUSINESS_SERVICE, moduleMetadata=BusinessServiceModuleMetadata [applicationName=package, path=consumersCovers, 
serviceLogicalId=consumersCovers, version=null, resource=null, subResource=null, routines=[RoutineModuleMetadata [routineId=package_serviceutils, dependsOn=[]]]], 
configurationProvider=BusinessServiceDeploymentConfigurationProvider [moduleMetadata=BusinessServiceModuleMetadata [applicationName=package, path=consumersCovers, serviceLogicalId=consumersCovers,
 version=null, resource=null, subResource=null, routines=[RoutineModuleMetadata [routineId=package_serviceutils, dependsOn=[]]]]], 
 configurationResources=[URL [jar:file:/opt/someCorp/RESOURCES/modules/someCorp/ctsrvs01/servicios/main/servicios/package_consumersCovers-sn.jar!/META-INF/spring/business-service.xml],
 URL [jar:file:/opt/someCorp/RESOURCES/modules/someCorp/ctsrvs01/rutinas/main/rutinas/package_serviceutils-rm.jar!/META-INF/spring/routine.xml]]]\t 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'srvConsumerCoversV01': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'srvIntConsumerCovers';
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'srvIntConsumerCovers': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'consumerCreditDAOImpl';
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'consumerCoversDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mfadt310Mapper'; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 
 'com.****.consumercovers.rm.utils.BackendMapper<com.****.consumercovers.dao.model.mfadt310_1.Request_1, 
 com.****.consumercovers.business.dto.DtoIntConsumerCover, com.****.consumercovers.dao.model.mfadt310_1.Response_1, 
 com.****.consumercovers.business.dto.DtoIntMessageResponse>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at com.someCorp.jee.arq.spring.core.servicing.deployment.ManagedServiceDeployment.doStart(ManagedServiceDeployment.java:91) ~[arq-spring-servicing-core-5.15.6.1.jar!/:?]
,   at com.someCorp.jee.arq.spring.core.servicing.deployment.ManagedServiceDeployment.checkDeployedAndStart(ManagedServiceDeployment.java:143) ~[arq-spring-servicing-core-5.15.6.1.jar!/:?]
,   at com.someCorp.jee.arq.spring.core.servicing.deployment.DeploymentManagerImpl.dispatch(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:319) ~[arq-spring-servicing-core-5.15.6.1.jar!/:?]
,   at com.someCorp.jee.arq.spring.core.servicing.startup.BusinessServiceModuleCXFServlet.invoke(BusinessServiceModuleCXFServlet.java:30) ~[arq-spring-servicing-core-5.15.6.1.jar!/:?]
,   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
,   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:225) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
,   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503) ~[jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec-2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001]
,   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at com.someCorp.jee.arq.spring.core.servicing.startup.ApiOriginFilter.doFilter(ApiOriginFilter.java:97) ~[arq-spring-servicing-core-5.15.6.1.jar!/:?]
,   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at com.someCorp.jee.arq.spring.core.servicing.startup.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:39) ~[arq-spring-servicing-core-5.15.6.1.jar!/:?]
,   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at com.someCorp.jee.arq.spring.core.servicing.invocation.RequestResponseContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestResponseContextFilter.java:32) ~[arq-spring-servicing-core-5.15.6.1.jar!/:?]
,   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) ~[?:?]
,   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) ~[undertow-core-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) ~[undertow-core-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) ~[undertow-core-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) ~[?:?]
,   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68) ~[?:?]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105) ~[?:?]
,   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1551) ~[?:?]
,   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1551) ~[?:?]
,   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1551) ~[?:?]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387) ~[undertow-core-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852) ~[undertow-core-2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001]
,   at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35) ~[jboss-threads-2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001]
,   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990) ~[jboss-threads-2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001]
,   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486) ~[jboss-threads-2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001]
,   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377) ~[jboss-threads-2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001]
,   at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282) ~[?:?]
,   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'srvIntConsumerCovers': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'consumerCreditDAOImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'consumerCoversDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mfadt310Mapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.****.consumercovers.rm.utils.BackendMapper<com.****.consumercovers.dao.model.mfadt310_1.Request_1, com.****.consumercovers.business.dto.DtoIntConsumerCover, com.****.consumercovers.dao.model.mfadt310_1.Response_1, com.****.consumercovers.business.dto.DtoIntMessageResponse>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   ... 84 more\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'consumerCoversDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mfadt310Mapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.****.consumercovers.rm.utils.BackendMapper<com.****.consumercovers.dao.model.mfadt310_1.Request_1, com.****.consumercovers.business.dto.DtoIntConsumerCover, com.****.consumercovers.dao.model.mfadt310_1.Response_1, com.****.consumercovers.business.dto.DtoIntMessageResponse>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
,   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
```

Comment: In this I don't find any error, everything looks fine. Can you share the controller as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject a bean that does not exist. You are trying to field inject BackendMapper but you did not register it as a bean. Therefore you are getting this error

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.****.consumercovers.rm.utils.BackendMapper<com.****.consumercovers.dao.model.mfadt310_1.Request_1, com.****.consumercovers.business.dto.DtoIntConsumerCover, com.****.consumercovers.dao.model.mfadt310_1.Response_1, com.****.consumercovers.business.dto.DtoIntMessageResponse>'
```

Currently BackendMapper does not qualify as a candidate for autowire. You have to first register it as a bean. There are several ways of doing that, use annotations `@Component`, `@Configuration`, `@Bean`, etc.

Comment: Interesting i actually changed that but the project is actually pretty extense. So it's possible to you to review the layers? im actually extremely stuck with this project https://bitbucket.org/lunaprojectdev/project-test/src/master/

Comment: It says repository not found

Comment: No way, can you check that again please? im really stuck!!